# pathname change causes Git not to recognize my repo

Tags: git, github, command-line, terminal

This is a minor inconvenience, but I'm curious as to why this is happening. And, if there is a simple reason and fix for it.

Previously, when using Terminal to push and pull files to GitHub, I would enter git init and then simply cd using the name of my repository.

like so:

```
$ git init
$ cd remote_repo_name
```

This would work how you'd expect, and I never thought anything of it.
After reorganizing some files, I created a 'dev' folder to hold *all* my repos in one place. But, that also means that I slightly changed the paths for each of the repos (instead of them all being in my Downloads folder, they are located in dev).

Now, when I try to 'cd' to my repo after entering 'git init', it gives me the error: "No such file or directory" even though all the repository names were unchanged. The 'cd' command only works when I copy the repo pathname into terminal (instead of simply typing its name).

i.e:

```
$ cd Users/dev/remote_repo_name
```

Any advice would be great! Thank you!

Comment: `git init` initializes a repo in the current directory, it knows nothing about `remote_repo_name`, so I'm not sure I understand your workflow.

Comment: What is the shells "current directory" when you run `cd Users/dev/remote_repo_name`?

Comment: There is something off in the usage you describe : can you please explain what you think your computer is doing when you run `git init` ?